# Insert data to database using foreach loop php

Tags: php

Ex: If I have code :

```
$data = array('a','b','c');
foreach($data as $val){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO db (`title`)VALUES('$val')");
}
```

I want to insert all data from variable $val how can I coding it ? 
please help !!!
thank !!

Comment: Please post the entire code. We cannot see how you are connecting to the data base. Also note that you're using a deprecated driver `mysql`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two things wrong which i can see at a glance.

1. `mysql` is deprecated, use `mysqli` instead. [Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php#migration55.deprecated)
2. Since you will have to switch over to `mysqli` you will need to reference your database connection every time you want to do a mysql database related operation, unless you do some PHP magic (classes or methods).

Other than these two i guess there is no problem in your code, the for loop should work perfectly fine.

Comment: I'm not test it, for this code it will insert all data in array right ?

Comment: @SopheakRotanak if you want the data in the array to insert into the database, then yes it will work (at least that's how it seems).